# Strange hotlink protection issues - .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I used the rules that should work, and have worked in the past but every variation I try it continues to serve a the image (clearing cache each time). Other rules like URL rewrites work fine.

I would provide a copy of the error logs but I can't seem to gain access to this through FTP, neither can the person running the server droplet.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(sub\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

I know this seems like it should all be working, everyone says the codes are correct. Yet for the past few weeks I have been trying find solutions. I'm positive there is something else going on that is not related to the code, I just need help finding it as I'm not too experienced working extensively with htaccess.

---

Full htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?dev.mangazing\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: It's important to place your code in the correct order in the .htaccess file. Please check that everything is in the right order so that this does not cause conflicts, your code should work, feel free to try the code in my answer below.. please add your full .htaccess file to your post (**without** informaifion about your website and server IP etc) if my code isn't working too.

Comment: @jagb Yeah, that code doesn't seem to work either. The full htaccess has been added to the question.

Comment: What do hotlink checkers return? [link](http://www.free-webhosts.com/hotlinking-checker.php) there are a lot more [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=hotlink+protection+checker) if you prefer to disallow blank refferers too, you might want to add `#`before the line or remove `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$` from your code. it's better to allow but you still can try, maybe this is what you want..

Comment: I've tried with and without. and the hotlink checkers all display the image, another thing. these images are bypassing the password protection too. I view them in a browser where I have not logged into and I can see the images, go to any other page, and it asks me to login.

Comment: Please try to replace your rewrite rule line with 'RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tatice/cristal-intense/256/Ad-Aware-icon.png [NC,R,L]' and visit 1 of **your** image urls, I hope this is working for you.. remember to upload a replacement to your server and change URL for the replacement, this can be done with a transparent 1 pixel image free hosted at google websites etc

Comment: Comment out your Auth code and see if those non-image files still give you error.

Comment: @jagb yeah, didn't make a difference. :\

Comment: @anubhava Not sure what changed but, before and after commenting out the Auth, it's correctly disaplaying the 404 now.

Comment: I'll add it to my answer below..

Comment: Well, something is working and better if you're able to see the 404 error handling, now we have to make the hotlinking rewrite rule work..

Comment: I'm not worried about what it's doing, I'm worried about that it's /not/ doing.

Comment: It's updated, but other than for a reason I'm not aware of, non existing images are showing correctly now, the main issue is still relevent, hotlink protection does not work.

Comment: @jagb yes I understand, I already did all of that when you said it in the comments, Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?sub.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]`

### EDIT

Please try to replace your rewrite rule line

Replace:

`RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]`

With:

`RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tatice/cristal-intense/256/Ad-Aware-icon.png [NC,R,L]`

**Your code will look like:**

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?sub.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tatice/cristal-intense/256/Ad-Aware-icon.png [NC,R,L]`

**Or**

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?dev.mangazing\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tatice/cristal-intense/256/Ad-Aware-icon.png [NC,R,L]`

and visit 1 of your image urls, I hope this is working for you.. remember to upload a replacement picture to a server and change replacement URL in the new rewrite rule, this can be done with a transparent 1 pixel image (Not a html/php etc document, it must be an image file!) free hosted at [google pages](https://sites.google.com) or any other webhosting service you like..

### Edit 2

Please try with `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
 #Your other anti hotlink commands here...
</IfModule>`

More methodes to protect image hotlinking: [**creating the ultimate .htaccess anti hotlinking strategy**](http://perishablepress.com/creating-the-ultimate-htaccess-anti-hotlinking-strategy/)